# python scipy cannot pass a dataframe generated from class attribute?

Tags: python, dataframe, numpy, scipy

I am learning a little bit about using classes to make my code easier to modify. I was working on defining a ml_setup class which calls a spearman calculation from a separate function.

```
class ml_setup:
    def __init__(self, df, dropcols, ycol, **kwargs ):
        self.ycol = ycol
        self.df = df  
        if 'stratify' in kwargs:
            self.stratify = kwargs['stratify']
        else:
            self.stratify = None
        self.train_Y = df[ycol]
        self.train_X = df.drop(columns=dropcols)
        if 'seed' in kwargs:
            self.seed = kwargs['seed']
        else:
            self.seed = self.seed_gen()
        if 'test' in kwargs:
            self.test = kwargs['test']
        else:
            self.test = 0.3
        if 'final_model' in kwargs:
            self.final_model = kwargs['final_model']
        else:
            self.final_model = None

    def seed_gen(self):
        seed = np.random.randint(0,2**32 - 1)
        return seed
    def linear_reg(self, positive=False):
        self.regr = linear_model.LinearRegression(positive=positive)    
        if self.final_model is None:
            self.X_train, self.X_test, self.y_train, self.y_test = train_test_split(self.train_X, self.train_Y, test_size=self.test, random_state=self.seed, shuffle=True, stratify=self.stratify)        
            #for test/train
            self.regr.fit(self.X_train, self.y_train)
            self.predictions = self.regr.predict(self.X_test)
            #print(y_test)
            #print(self.predictions)
            #print(self.y_test[self.ycol])
            self.p, self.s = pearson_stat(self.y_test[self.ycol], self.predictions, print_out='no')
            self.r2 = r_squared(self.y_test, self.predictions)
```

and the pearson_stat function look like the following,

```
def pearson_stat (x_data, y_data, print_out='no'):
    import scipy.stats as ss
    p = ss.pearsonr(x_data, y_data)
    s = ss.spearmanr(x_data, y_data)
    if print_out == 'yes':
        print('Pearson rho = {:.4f}, P = {:.4g}'
                  .format(*p))
        print('Spearman r = {:.4f}, P = {:.4g}'
                  .format(*s))
    return p[0], s[0]
```

While this code perfectly works if I pass the x and y to pearson_stat function following way.

```
a, s = pearson_stat(ml_mods[seed].y_test['exp_val'],ml_mods[seed].y_test['exp_val'])
```

But if I now set the 'exp_val' from the class attribute, it doesn't work. gives me the following error.

```
a, s = pearson_stat(ml_mods[seed].y_test[ml_mods[seed].ycol],ml_mods[seed].y_test[ml_mods[seed].ycol])

xmean = x.mean(dtype=dtype)
  File "../anaconda3/envs/py3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/_methods.py", line 160, in _mean
     ret = umr_sum(arr, axis, dtype, out, keepdims)
TypeError: No loop matching the specified signature and casting was found for ufunc add
```

Can you help me understand this?

Comment: Examine the changed argument.  What's different.  Don't expect us to deduce that by just reading the code.

Comment: The only change I did is basically adding the column name using "ml_mods[seed].ycol". ycol attribute in ml_mods[seed] class is basically a list with one element.
 ml_mods[seed].ycol equals to ['exp_val']

So technically question I have is why python throws no error when I specifically pass it by mentioning the list directly rather passing the list via an attribute of a class.

Comment: What I want you to test, or otherwise verify, is  what happens when you make that change.  What **is** `ml_mods[seed].y_test[ml_mods[seed].ycol]`?  Not what you intend it to be or hope, but it actually is.  For example indexing a data frame with a column name is different from indexing it with a list containing the same name.  `pearson_stat` is getting something different.  It's your job to discover what!

Comment: Oh I see. I just realized what's going on. I only looked at the output of 
ml_mods[seed].y_test[ml_mods[seed].ycol]
and 
ml_mods[seed].y_test['exp_val']
Bothe gave me the same output (from the look of it). But now I checked the type of the output. And it actually gave two different data types
> type(ml_mods[seed].y_test[ml_mods[seed].ycol])
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
> type(ml_mods[seed].y_test['exp_val'])
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
I wonder why "ml_mods[seed].ycol" resulted in an output form of DataFrame when ['exp_val'] and ml_mods[seed].ycol both have type list

Comment: BTW, Thanks a lot for directing me for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

So after the direction from @hpaulj I realized that the way I call for the column resulted in a DataFrame rather than a Series. For Pearson calculation, I needed the data in form of Series (i.e., array-like).

```
type(ml_mods[seed].y_test[ml_mods[seed].ycol]) 
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'> 
type(ml_mods[seed].y_test['exp_val']) 
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
```